# Android Bottom Navigation bar 4 Items not showing properly on some devices

Tags: android, material-design, navbar

I got a little problem, as I'm trying to add 4 Icons to a Bottom Navigation Bar in Android.

[On some devices it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU7iF.png)

[But I want it to be looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYs0p.png)

How to achieve that ? Thanks in advance

Don't know which code you need. Just added everything used by the viewpager for the Bottom navigation Bar

```
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_stdplan:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_klausur:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_hausaufgaben:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_fehlzeiten:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });



    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (prevMenuItem != null) {
                prevMenuItem.setChecked(false);
            }
            else
            {
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
            }
            Log.d("page", "onPageSelected: "+position);
            bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
            prevMenuItem = bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    setupViewPager(viewPager);
}
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    stdplanFragment =new StdplanFragment();
    klausurenFragment =new KlausurenFragment();
    hausaufgabenFragment =new HausaufgabenFragment();
    fehlzeitenFragment =new FehlzeitenFragment();
    adapter.addFragment(stdplanFragment);
    adapter.addFragment(klausurenFragment);
    adapter.addFragment(hausaufgabenFragment);
    adapter.addFragment(fehlzeitenFragment);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

bottom_navigation.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_stdplan"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/tab1"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_klausur"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"
        android:title="@string/tab2"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_hausaufgaben"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Hausaufgaben"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_fehlzeiten"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_recent_history"
        android:title="@string/tab3"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @Ahmed done adding the code. Didn't know what exactly to add

Comment: Anyone who will be looking at your code will want to look at where and how you added the bottom navigation.

Comment: Reload. I think I added everything necessary

Comment: Have you followed some sort of a tutorial?

Comment: @Ahmed Just for properly adding the Bottom Navigation Bar. How can I achieve the effect from the second image ? Title just showing if item selected

Comment: I think I have to add this to the  onPageSelected(int position) method. But I don't know what to add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it myself by changing the font size of the titles

Everyone else struggling with this: Just add these two lines to your dimens.xml

```
  <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size" tools:override="true">10sp</dimen>
  <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">10sp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem from a smallest thing possible. Not sure if it has anything to do with the image icons you have used, but can you please see if the image icons happen to have any paddings i.e. in the image itself?

Also for debugging purposes please remove the titles or keep them empty and see if it aligns the image icons properly.

Can you please change the following,

```
app:showAsAction="never"
```

to

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

I would try following this [link](https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0) just in case.

Comment: No, the icons don't have any margins. I changed the line you mentioned. Still nothing. I will try removing the titles

Comment: I removed the text. Now it looks properly. But I need the text. So what can I do ?

Comment: Did you added showasaction="ifRoom"? Add the text back along with changing each and every never to ifRoom

Comment: I did. Read my answer. It's fixed